# call SharePoint's add new webpart function from within a web part component (spfx-reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, web-parts, pnp-js

I'm just new to reactjs-spfx controls. I have a pnpjs control that lists all the pages and it's contents. I should be able to add edit and delete pages using that web part. I want to include in that component the functionality to add a new Web part to the page content when I'm editing it. How do you call that functionality from SharePoint to add new webpart? Please see below picture. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using pnpjs library for this, it wraps most basic tasks with a nice api. I am adding my own webpart to a page something like this, just to give you an idea:

See https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/clientside-pages/

```js
const sp = SPFI(...)

// or get the existing page
const page = await sp.web.addClientsidePage(fileName, title);
const section = page.addSection();

const partDefs = await sp.web.getClientsideWebParts();

// find the web part we want to add by guid
const myPartDef = partDefs.find(c => areGuidsEqual(c.Id, MY_GUID));

const part = ClientsideWebpart.fromComponentDef(myPartDef);
part.setProperties({
  someProp: someValue
});

section.addControl(part);
await page.save();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this. I'll mark your answer later. This might be the answer I 'm looking for.

Comment: your answer is partly right but I want to directly call the SharePoint Add webpart dialog box See pic.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bX8cqaYBcUvzL9lFg67IPIcgMmcSmXfk/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: That is not possible of course. this dialog is a part of sharepoint product itself